# Unconventional plugin name in CakePHP 1.3

Tags: cakephp, plugins, naming-conventions

Is it possible to place a plugin named 'Apple' in a folder 'Orange' in CakePHP 1.3?

Like so:

- controllers
- models
- plugins

  - Orange

    - apple_app_controller.php
    - apple_app_model.php
    - controllers

      - posts_controller.php (extends AppleAppController)
      - comments_controller.php (extends AppleAppController)
    - models

      - post.php (extends AppleAppModel)
      - comment.php (extends AppleAppModel)
    - views

      - ...
- views

  - ...

Essentially, the plugin is named "Apple", just the folder name is "Orange". How can this be done in CakePHP 1.3? (I'm OK with modifying the core)

Comment: That sounds like a recipe for a catastrophe, why would you even want to do that?

Comment: @ndm The main app is our core product, and certain clients have custom functionality in the form of controller, action, or view overrides. We maintain these customizations as a plugin. Each client is under a different git branch in the plugin. So the plugin name is constant (client), and we want the controllers and models to change.

Comment: So the folder is part of these individual git branches and differs per client? If that's the case, what is the advantage over using a static folder name? Making such modifications to the core will open a can of worms, I'd really really suggest to not even try.

Comment: The plugin folder is a submodule and has a static name "client".

Comment: Ok, I misread that, but still what's the advantage over leaving everything static? `ClientAppController` or `AppleAppController`, doesn't make much of a difference, does it?